# Multi-factor authentication throught Microsoft Graph in Web app

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an existing web application which is used for HR, managing tasks, sending forms and so on.
My client wants me to integrate Microsoft's multi-factor authentication when signing resources, forms and other stuff.

For now, the signing process is just a token that is generated and sent by email, so the users have to click a link to sign it. My goal here is to give users the possibility to also choose to sign whatever they're signing with multi-factor authentication through their own Microsoft account.

The only thing I've done so far is managing to log in and authorize with the Microsoft Graph API and get Calendar events and other stuff from the user.

Of course, I've googled a lot - but I haven't found the right documentation for my use case. So I need someone to pin point me to the right documentation for my use case. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my investigation on this issue, I have not seen a direct way of signing files and other resources as well as enabling MFA via the Graph API. I however saw a feature request related to enabling MFA via a Graph API call [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/17964397-possibility-to-enable-disable-multi-factor-authent). Please consider upvoting it

Comment: Can it be done the way I'm looking for with Azure AD B2C?